# WPF TextBox set common StringFormat for all controls

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, textbox, string-formatting

Is it possible to make something to set StringFormat of Binding property for all (or part of) TextBoxes in project? Yes, I can write something like

```
<TextBox x:Name="SetPosition" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxSmallStyle}" Text="{Binding SetPosition, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat='{}{0:#0.0}'}" />
```

but setting it for many identical TextBoxes it too boring ))) As you see I am used Style which include Heigth, Width e.t.c. I can't override Binding property in Style because need to use this Style with any Binding Path properties but Binding overrides only wholly.
Are where any workarounds exists?
P.S. I am already using not standard TextBox but overrided control for my special functionality. Can I override Binding for using compoment's code-behind, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you have already extended `TextBox` you can simply enhance that type and modify the existing `Binding` on the `TextBox.Text` property.

The following example shows how the `ExtendedTextBox` allows to provide a string format expression which is assigned to the current `Binding`.
Any locally set `Binding.StringFormat` values are overwritten with the `ExtendedTextBox.TextStringFormat` property value.
If you also want to apply the string formatting when there is no `Binding` set on the `Text` property, you would have to monitor the `Text` property for changes.

```cs
public class ExtendedTextBox : TextBox
{
  public string TextStringFormat
  {
    get => (string)GetValue(TextStringFormatProperty);
    set => SetValue(TextStringFormatProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty TextStringFormatProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "TextStringFormat",
    typeof(string),
    typeof(ExtendedTextBox),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(string), OnTextStringFormatChanged));

  // Monitor TextBox.Text property for changes to reapply the format string
  static ExtendedTextBox() => TextBox.TextProperty.OverrideMetadata(
    typeof(ExtendedTextBox), 
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnTextChanged));

  public ExtendedTextBox()
    => this.Loaded += OnLoaded;

  private static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) 
    => ((ExtendedTextBox)d).ApplyTextPropertyFormatString();

  private static void OnTextStringFormatChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    var extendedTextBox = (ExtendedTextBox)d;
    string oldFormatString = (string)e.OldValue;
    string newFormatString = (string)e.NewValue;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newFormatString))
    {
      extendedTextBox.ApplyTextPropertyFormatString();
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(oldFormatString))
    {
      extendedTextBox.ClearTextPropertyFormatString();
    }
  }

  private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    => ApplyTextPropertyFormatString();

  private void ApplyTextPropertyFormatString()
  {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.TextStringFormat))
    {
      return; 
    }

    BindingBase textBinding = BindingOperations.GetBindingBase(this, TextBox.TextProperty);
    if (textBinding is null)
    {
      // No binding attached. 
      // Apply format string directly on the Text property.

      string formattedText;
      if (double.TryParse(this.Text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat, out double number))
      {
        formattedText = string.Format(this.TextStringFormat, number);
      }
      else
      {
        formattedText = string.Format(this.TextStringFormat, this. Text);
      }

      SetCurrentValue(TextBox.TextProperty, formattedText);
    }
    else
    {
      // Apply format string via Binding.

      textBinding = CloneObject(textBinding);
      textBinding.StringFormat = this.TextStringFormat;
      _ = SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, textBinding);  
    }
  }

  private void ClearTextPropertyFormatString()
  {
    BindingBase textBinding = BindingOperations.GetBindingBase(this, TextBox.TextProperty);
    if (textBinding is null)
    {     
      return;
    }

    textBinding = CloneObject(textBinding);
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBinding.StringFormat))
    {
      textBinding.StringFormat = null;
      _ = SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, textBinding);
    }
  }

  private TObject CloneObject<TObject>(TObject objectToClone)
  {
    string xamlObject = XamlWriter.Save(objectToClone);
    return (TObject)XamlReader.Parse(xamlObject);
  }
}
```

**App.xaml**
Define a global `Style` that defines the actual string format:

```xml
<Style TargetType="ExtendedTextBox">
  <Setter Property="TextStringFormat"
          Value="{}{0:#0.0}" />
</Style>
```